# How to represent a JSON structure as an organizational tree in HTML?

Tags: html, json, hierarchical-data

I have a nested json object which represents a one to many relationship between a parent node and its children. I want to represent this json as an organizational chart in HTML. I found that I can use Google Charts to do it but I am not sure if Google Charts give you the ability to design the boxes or do any modifications on the design.

Does anyone know any resources that I can study?

This is the json object I have constructed:

```
{ 'id': 1,
  'name': 'Parent Node',
  'description': 'First Parent Node',
  'children': [
  {
      'id': 2,
      'name': 'child1',
      'description': 'child1',
      'children': [
      {
          'id': 4,
          'name': 'grand1',
          'description': 'grand1',
          'children': []
       }]
   },
   {
       'id': 3,
       'name': 'child2',
       'description': 'child2',
       'children': []
   }]
 }
```

This question [Representing Binary Tree Structure in Web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20946994/representing-binary-tree-structure-in-web-browser) is also similar, but the link does not seem to work.

Comment: Hi, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please read the [help], specifically the pages on [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). [*"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic"*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @GalAbra I didn't try anything because I don't know where to start from. I am asking for any resources that I can study to help me start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Tree map in HTML using json object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44186794/create-tree-map-in-html-using-json-object)

Comment: I literally just searched your question on Google :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working version of the link from the other question that you mentioned: http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of how exactly you want your display to be like, so here are two viable answers :

- You just want the hierarchy :
  Just iterate through recursively through your JSON and create **ul** and **li** tags, then add a CSS to improve (you might find something tailored to your need on Codepen.io) or use the link from the other post you found ( http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview-with-multiple-node-selection.html and http://experiments.wemakesites.net/css3-treeview.html )
- You want it to be displayed smoothly and don't mind using an external library :
  Use something like : https://www.graphdracula.net/ or one of those listed here https://dzone.com/articles/top-5-javascript-libraries-to-create-an-org-chart . You'll need to transform your data to match the way the library needs, but it's usually worth the pain.